# Is it possible to verify a node is running remotely?

Tags: go-ethereum, nodes

I am trying to run many different nodes remotely and I was asking if it were possible to verify they are running remotely. Is it possible to verify a running Geth-node remotely?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can try to ping **TCP port 30303**, which Ethereum use for P2P connections.

For example:

```
nc -vz localhost 30303
```

Check also question at Superuser for more info how to ping a TCP port:
https://superuser.com/questions/769541/is-it-possible-to-ping-an-addressport

Comment: Thanks! This way I would know that it could be alive. But it also could just be any machine with the port 30303 open. I am trying to verify the node is actually running